# HP Photosmart C4780 doesn't feed the Paper

Tags: printer, hp-photosmart

My photosmart wireless printer boots up fine but when I send it a job it attempts to 'grasp' at the paper in the tray and while it appears to catch the top sheet as normal at first, it only succeeds in making a winding noise without actually feeding the sheet into the printer.

Can this be easily fixed? I've had it over a year now but I've hardly made more than 10 printouts with it.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

- Use different amounts of paper in the paper tray - from one to full.
- Check the paper tray for any defects.
- Clean the paper pickup roller with a little methylated spirit and a soft cloth.